# Interview: how to get last clicked option at the top across all sessions for a particular user in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Suppose we have 4 options like

```
option1
option2 
option3 
option4
```

If user clicks on `option4` the sequence should be like this:

```
option4 
option1
option2 
option3
```

where option4 is at the top. When user clicks `option2` the sequence should be like:

```
option2 
option4 
option1
option3
```

where option2 is at top. Like this system should maintain the option sequence for all users according to last option selected.

Even if we insert last selected record in database how will we get the record in same sequence? Even if we order it by serial number there can be a case where user can click on `option4` 10 times which will insert `option4` 10 times in database. How do I track the last selected option when particular user logs on to system?

How do I achieve this across every user session? When any user logs on he should get his last selected option in the system.

Comment: You've almost got a stack, but you'll need the ability to remove a duplicated item from the middle (if the user clicks on the same one again). [Here are some ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/q/748387/314291)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you store your data/log like this:

```
user | option | dateTime
-----+--------+----------------------
1    | 4      | 2015-04-25 10:50:01
1    | 3      | 2015-04-25 10:50:02
2    | 4      | 2015-04-25 10:50:02
1    | 2      | 2015-04-25 10:50:03
....
```

In this table you can get 4 last/recent options like this:

```
SELECT TOP(4) [option]
FROM [LOG]
WHERE [user] = 1
ORDER BY [dateTime] DESC
```

---

If you want to ignore repeated logs for one option you need `GROUP BY` keyword like this:

```
SELECT TOP(4) [option]
FROM [LOG]
WHERE [user] = 1
GROUP BY [option]
ORDER BY max([dateTime]) DESC
```

Comment: How do you create database/code samples so quickly? I had the same idea but you explained it with samples :)

Comment: Almost correct. You're missing `DISTINCT` after `TOP(4)`.

Comment: @Sander thanks, I use `GROUP BY` instead of that ;).

Comment: @shA.t :Why did you use max(datetime)?Doesnt order by datetime desc and select top(4) give us required result?

Comment: @Tejas If it gives you the required result, use it, But I think you can't use it when you don't have `[datetime]` after `GROUP BY` ;).

Comment: @shA.t,@Sander:Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

You could save the last moment of clicking in a DateTime, per option, per user, in the database. That way, if you retrieve the options for the users from the database, all you have to do is sort them on the DateTime field, descending.

This solves your ordering problem, as well as the problem that a user can click the same option four times. It would just update the DateTime for that user/option combination for times, but not result in duplicate rows.

Comment: Your solution is that the OP needs ;).

Comment: @pyrocimulus:Thanks for helping me out.